# Cannot add Chef client from Chef workstation because of private key AWS

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, chef, ssh-keys

I'm trying to create a node from a ubuntu workstation using Chef on an Ubuntu 16.04 AWS Server

I can SSH between devices using

```
sudo ssh -i "/path/to/private/key.pem" ubuntu@ip_address
```

This works fine ^^

HOWEVER

When I do:

```
knife bootstrap ip_address -x ubuntu -A -P password --sudo --use-sudo-password -N client_name
```

It cannot authenticate because the nature of AWS SSH is that it's asking for a private key not a password.

specifically I get

```
ERROR: Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ubuntu@ip_address
```

Answer (score 1):

solved with this

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

and then with

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```